# Get PermissionsBoundary based on Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to invoke  [IAM.Client.list_users](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_roles) AWS documentation in my lambda . As per the documentation, the document contains 
`'PermissionsBoundary': {
                'PermissionsBoundaryType': 'PermissionsBoundaryPolicy',
                'PermissionsBoundaryArn': 'string'
            }`

But for the call,I am trying to invoke the following API call `PermissionsBoundary` is missing

`client = boto3.client('iam')
    roles = client.list_roles()
   for role in roles['Roles']:
        print(role)`

But the response I am getting is

`{
    'Path': '/service-role/',
    'RoleName': 'send-sns-1',
    'RoleId': 'ABCDEF123456ACBD',
    'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::13456798:role/service-role/send-sns-1',
    'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 4, 15, 22, 50, tzinfo = tzlocal()),
    'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Principal': {
                'Service': 'lambda.amazonaws.com'
            },
            'Action': 'sts:AssumeRole'
        }]
    },
    'MaxSessionDuration': 3600
}`

The role of lambda function has `IAMFullAccess` permission.

What is that I am missing, to get `'PermissionsBoundary': {....}`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is wrong, and only `GetRole` and `GetUser` currently display the permissions boundary. I've filed an issue about it [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/iam-user-guide/issues/81) but in the meantime I think you'll need to issue `GetUser`/`GetRole` repeatedly for every user/role in your account if you want to enumerate all boundaries.